# Adding custom date to DateTimeField in Django?

Tags: python, django

Say I have a model with a field as such:

`begin_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)`

Whenever I want to add a date using a string, for example, `'2020-06-15T11:00'` it gives me the `RuntimeWarning: received a naive datetime while time zone support is active`.

So what's the proper way of adding date to a model in Django?

Comment: If you add `Z`, it is in UTC: `'2020-06-15T11:00Z'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a `'Z'` suffix, you specify the datetime in UTC, for the [ISO 8601 standard [Django-doc]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```
'2020-06-15T11:00Z'
```

You can however also pass a `datetime` object:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import UTC

datetime(2020, 6, 15, 11, 00, tzinfo=UTC)
```